# Firebase limitToFirst acting strangely

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase node that has 4 objects in it. It looks like this:

```
'messages': {
    '-FirebaseId_1': { ... },
    '-FirebaseId_2': { ... },
    '-FirebaseId_3': { ... },
    '-FirebaseId_4': { ... }
}
```

I'm running to different tests and getting strange results.

```
function retreive(amount) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('messages');
    ref = ref.orderByKey();
    ref = ref.limitToFirst(amount);
    ref.once('value').then(function(groupSnapshot) {
        console.log('Snapshot:', groupSnapshot.val());
    });
}
```

Executing `retreive(1), retreive(2), retreive(3), retreive(4)` yeild the appropriate results of only returning 1-4 values

I can put ANY number in the `retreive(#)` call over *4* and retreive all of the values, **as expected**.

However, if I am to do `limitToFirst(11)` I only get two results, not 4.  This problem does not exist with anything other then the number 11 from my tests (1-100)

I mean this isn't a huge deal to me, as I can just pull 12 items and hide two off-screen for pagination instead of one, but I wanted to make sure this was expected behavior.

Comment: Works with 11 just as well for me: http://jsbin.com/goxalih/edit?js,console. If the problem persists for you, can you set up a similar jsbin that reproduces it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Before I break my back trying to recreate, I'm using the iOS / Android SDK with a bridge to javascript for react-native. So I'm actually using the Android SDK with this error. (haven't tested iOS) will that have any difference in how the query is generated? It don't think it would, but want to make sure first.